# Finding the largest sum of disjoint leaf-to-leaf paths in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need advice on a task where I am looking for disjoint paths leading from leaf to leaf (they must not return along the same path/edge) so that their sum creates the greatest possible value, i.e. the paths must not intersect and must be as good as possible belongs to the total. And be careful, the point (root) where the path breaks is not included in the total sum, viz. picture.

I don't know how to solve the problem at all. I am attaching code that tries to decide whether to choose a path by one leaf or to choose a smaller subtree, but it does not work correctly.

If anyone has any study material I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance
All program
https://onecompiler.com/c/3ymb7xvzn

```
int depth(struct node *root, int *res)
{
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    
    int l = depth(root->left, res);
    int r = depth(root->right, res);
    
    int max_single_best_Way = max(l+root->data, r+root->data);

    int max_root = l+r;
    
    int maximum = max(max_single_best_Way, max_root);
    *res = max(*res, maximum);

    return maximum;

}
```

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

I was unable to create an algorithm to solve the problem. I would like some advice, study materials that I could use in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the function, `f`, our overall task, with input parameter a root to a tree. Let's call the function, `g`, the maximum continuously descending path from a given node, including the node, that also adds the result of `f` for each node not chosen.

Starting at the root of the tree, in a run of `f`, for each node, we can either assign it (1) as a parent in a path, or (2) not part of any path. In the case of (1), we'd like `g(left_child) + g(right_child)`. In the case of (2), we'd like `f(left_child) + f(right_child)`.

Python code with your second example, where the root is not part of any path:

```py
def g(tree):
  if tree == None:
    return 0
  return tree["val"] + max(
    g(tree["l"]) + f(tree["r"]),
    g(tree["r"]) + f(tree["l"])
  )

def f(tree):
  if tree == None:
    return 0
  return max(
    g(tree["l"]) + g(tree["r"]),
    f(tree["l"]) + f(tree["r"])
  )
  
tree = {
  "val": 0,
  
  "l": {
    "val": 2,
    
    "l": {
      "val": 2,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    },
    
    "r": {
      "val": 3,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    }
  },
  
  "r": {
    "val": 1,
    
    "l": {
      "val": 2,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    },
    
    "r": {
      "val": 3,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    }
  }
}

print(f(tree)) # 10
```

Your third example:

```py
tree = {
  "val": 0,
  
  "l": {
    "val": 6,
    
    "l": {
      "val": 5,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    },
    
    "r": {
      "val": 3,
      "l": None,
      "r": None
    }
  },
  
  "r": {
    "val": 5,
    
    "l": {
      "val": 7,
      
      "l": {
        "val": 3,
        "l": None,
        "r": None
      },
    
      "r": {
        "val": 6,
        "l": None,
        "r": None
      }
    },
    
    "r": {
      "val": 7,
      
      "l": {
        "val": 6,
        "l": None,
        "r": None
      },
    
      "r": {
        "val": 7,
        "l": None,
        "r": None
      }
    }
  }
}

print(f(tree)) # 42
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, it solves my situation and it's understandable, but it's very difficult for me to create similar code, would you have some tips, study materials how to learn to write such tree traversal for other similiary tasks?

Comment: I don't know about study materials. I learned a lot by reading questions here with the tag, "algorithm," and trying to understand solutions and solve myself.

Comment: Hi, I'm still thinking about simplifying this task, can't there be an even simpler solution? Today I discussed it with a teacher at the university and perhaps it could be solved in a similar way as I outlined in the post, i.e. if you count the values ​​of disjoint paths and the sum for each subtree. But I don't really know how to do it

Comment: @Martin1541 I'm not sure I follow the idea. Could you perhaps add to the question description, describing in words the data that would be calculated and the decisions that would be made by a program that followed your idea for a specific, non-trivial example?

Comment: Look at the last picture. The point is that you calculate the values ​​for when you go over the top and and the path when you use disjoint subtrees and in recursion you decide which is the better choice

Comment: @Martin1541 I'm still not following. Isn't the solution I offered deciding in recursion which is the better choice when using disjoint subtrees and calculating values when you go over the top?

Comment: but the solution does not work fast for big data. when I'm on the PC I'll send an example

Comment: @Martin1541 oh, the code I posted does not include memoisation [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). It's just proof of concept.

Comment: @Martin1541 I haven't thought it through but it looks like we might be able to table and calculate bottom-up, as well.

Comment: That's something I was trying to imply, but I probably didn't say it correctly in English

Comment: I'll look into it when I have time, thanks for the link